# how to replace a language identifier in a URL?

Tags: php, regex

I need some help I have written the following preg_replace. The idea of the script is to get the language name from the domain name:

If I have a

```
http://www.domainname.com/nl/this/is/a/test/index.asp
```

I would like to strip the `(nl)` part from the domain name. The nl is a variable for languages so it could be:

- http://www.domainname.com/nl/this/is/a/test/index.asp
- http://www.domainname.com/fr/this/is/a/test/index.asp
- http://www.domainname.com/de/this/is/a/test/index.asp

The above domains represents language directories...

```
<?php
$sitename = "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$pagename = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."this/is/a/test";
$language = "\/..\/";
$language1 = preg_replace("/$language/", "$1", "$pagename");
?>
```

- I am only using the script where I know there will be a language directory.
- The script above also removes the this/a/test/ the (is) from the url. (which tells me the script is greedy.

What would be the best method to grab the language from the url?

Can someone please provide me with some guidence.

Thanks

This is the script I came up using the advice below:

```
<?php
$mainurl = "http://" .$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$fullpagename = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$mainlanguage = preg_replace('%^/(\w+?)/.*$%', '$1', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$strippedpagename = preg_replace("/$mainlanguage\//", '$1', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
?> 
<?php echo "Full URL: ".$mainurl ?><br>
<?php echo "Full Page Name: ".$fullpagename  ?><br>
<?php echo "Language: ".$mainlanguage ?><br>
<?php echo "Page Name No Language: ".$strippedpagename ?><br>
```

Exactly what I needed, or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like you are really just replacing $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] with $language...if that is the case, why not just use $language in your $pagename assignment to begin with?

Comment: how do I define the languages for all the different ones, this way I have one file, that finds the language for me?

Comment: okay wait I get it now, sorry, misunderstood the question

Comment: out of curiosity: why "replace" when you really just want to "extract"?

Comment: Note that `preg_replace` replaces *all* occurrences and not just the first one. So your second call of `preg_replace` will remove all occurrences of the language identifier followed by a `/`; something like `/en/eden/` would become just `/ed`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am very new to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$language = preg_replace('%^/(\w+?)/.*$%', '$1', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])
```

Comment: Just checked it again, and it is replacing a folder even if the folder is longer that 2 characters long, is there a way that I can set it so that it only remove 2 characters if it is the first /da/

Comment: Sure, replace `\w+?` with `\w{2}` in the above expression.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more simple:

```
$language = reset( explode('/', substr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],1) ) );
```

No need of regexp here.